# Create a Class with a creator like [NSArray array]

Tags: ios, class

I've written one ages ago but I can't find it now.

How do you create a creator function for a class that uses the same syntax as `[NSArray array];`?

i.e.

```
+ (id)object;
```

Instead of...

```
- (id)initWithBlah...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a **constructor** and a typical implementation may be

```
+ (NSArray *)array
{
    return [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Gah, yeah, I knew it wasn't a creator but I couldn't remember the name. Thanks! :D

Comment: I think it's called a "convenience constructor" or something